# How can I transfer my Pokémon from XY to ORAS with one 3DS and without Pokébank?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I have one 3DS and would like to transfer a Pokémon from XY to ORAS, but don't have access to the Pokébank at this time. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply, you get the pokemon you want to transfer and go onto the GTS (**Do not put a legendary in it**)

Next, you put a bad pokemon in the GTS and ask for the pokemon you want to trade. 
Make a message that will stand out to you, then make its restrictions fit for the pokemon your trading.
Send the pokemon to the GTS. **Save after that**.
Go to the home menu and close your game,
Swap the game from XY to ORAS (*Or vice versa*)

Then, go back onto the GTS in the Other game and look for the Bad Pokémon you sent. Once you find it, trade the pokemon that you asked for. **Save**

And there you go, you have transferred your pokemon.

Comment: This seems like the worst thing ever, but I guess beggars can't be choosers, eh :P

Comment: Ya, not rly safe haha, but it works. I would do this too. You really can't lose as long as you put the bad pokemon out first in the offer, and then accept with the good one that you want traded. If someone takes your bad pokemon for whatever odd reason, well now you have a new good pokemon for free.

Comment: @gitsitgo I suggest you probably catch a lot of Zubats or some other bad pokemon for it to be really easy.

Comment: Use Magikarps. Nobody wants to trade anything for a Magikarp; and if they do, lucky for you I guess :D

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use 2 consoles, one with XY and the other with ORAS and simply trade all the Pokemon you need. (Of course with the help of a friend, if you don't own another console.)

That's faster and definitely safer than putting them on GTS. There are more "thiefs" than you think, trust me.

Comment: That's why I said: Put the Bad Pokémon in, Not The good one.

Comment: Ok, that's not so bad, I admit it. Anyway it's a long process.

Comment: @pinckerman - It might be the only option if you don't have a second 3DS or can't shell out the $5 for the Pokebank

Comment: @Robotnik Not being able to shell out the $5 a year for Pokebank would literally mean being unemployed in a country with no social protection system whatsoever. This process takes considerably longer, to transfer, say, 10 Pokemon, you easily need an hour with this method, while Pokebank does it in a minute. So you've just used 59 minutes to save $5. It's not hard to get $5 for an hour's work. And that's assuming all he ever wants to do is transfer 10 Pokemon. Increase the number, and suddenly you work many, many hours or even days for those $5.

Comment: @scenia - Or they're between the ages of 8-15, without a part time job nor regular pocket money, don't have a credit/debit card, so have to purchase the $20 wallet recharge card (the lowest one IIRC) after convincing their parents to take them to the shopping centre and yes, that it's really what they want to spend their money on.

Comment: @Robotnik even at ages 8-15, earning $5 a year by doing some parent/uncle/aunt/whoever some favor really isn't much of a problem. It doesn't have to be official work for an employer, we're talking about $5 within an entire year.

Comment: @scenia - again, probably would have to be $20 to purchase a eshop wallet recharge card. Also: coming from a family where pocket money was tightly regulated, AND where my father is against anything 'internet' related, I can tell you that convincing him to allow me to spend my pocket money on the Pokebank would've been impossible. Not everyone has the same living conditions growing up - one of my friends earned his pocket money and had to put it up for 'board' once he entered year 7.

Comment: I am just going to say, I find it wise I don't spend my own money on something that I could do. If you guys think it takes time, then don't do it! Just waste your 5 bucks on getting PokeBank. OR use another $200-$300 on another 3DS.